# How do I install linux?

Tags: install

just wondered if anyone would be able to help me install elementary os?

I installed it years ago and it was great but I'm having a headache trying to install it on a newer laptop, and haven't used linux or windows for years.

I have a lenovo ideapad 1 (11ADA05) with windows 10 amd 3020e. I used etcher to burn the iso to a USB it didn't boot, so reset the boot order and I had a verification fail. I turned off secure boot and I could boot in to elementary.

When I tried elementary, I had no wifi (windows says the adapter is a realtek 8822ce.)

But biggest issue is when I look at gparted I can only see the usb drive. So when I try to install elementary it won't see the ssd, which is a ramaxel 64gb emmc drive.

I'm not sure if their are any more bios settings I can monkey around with? And when exiting elementary I'm sure I see an error but it doesn't stay up long enough for me to see what it says.

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Rob

Comment: Based on [this hardware probe report](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=5885335d44), this will not be an easy machine to get any distribution of Linux installed on. A good bit of the hardware is incredibly proprietary and designed solely for use by Windows. While there are ways to get some of the devices working, such as the eMMC storage, the end result may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I might have it working now. I made an ubuntu usb drive, to check if the wifi works and it did so that's my only problem with elementary os now. I made a windows usb drive, pretended to install it deleted all the partitions and now ubuntu can see the emmc harddrive. I will probably install ubuntu and then figure out elementary os from there. Thank you again

Comment: Glad you could work it out.

Comment: I actually didn't fix it lol... I got confused between internal emmc and an sd card I had plugged in. I installed kernal 5.13 on ubuntu running from sd card and it can now see my emmc! Getting there... but not sure how to build an iso with the kernal, guess I'll do some more reading!